# Unable to create OpenShift Cluster on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, openshift, redhat-containers

While creating an OpenShift Dedicated Cluster on GCP getting the following error and was not able to create the cluster.

```
Error creating cluster
CLUSTERS-MGMT-500: undefined
Operation ID: 0f75f788-0a31-4225-9e00-61e8e9e302fa
```

I am learning OpenShift4 and during hands-on, I tried creating a cluster through redhat console on GCP. I am having OpenShift Free trial (upgradeable) subscription. On GCP I have created the service account and assigned the suggested roles by the OpenShift to that service account and used that service account to create a VM in GCP via GCP Compute Engine. Finally generated the keys for that service account and passed that JSON key file during cluster creation on OpenShift console.

After configuring everything when I try to click the Create Cluster button I am getting the above-mentioned Error.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out that apart from assigning the following roles (DNS Administrator, Organisation Policy Viewer, Owner, Project IAM Admin, Service Management Administrator, Service Usage Admin, Storage Admin) to the `osd-ccs-admin` `IAM Service account` while creating or before creating the VM through `Compute engine`, following google APIs also needs to be enabled from the console or CLI.

These APIs can be enabled from the `gcloud` command through the script at once or can be executed one by one.

```
gcloud services enable compute.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable cloudapis.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable dns.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable iam.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable iamcredentials.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable servicemanagement.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable serviceusage.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable storage.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable storage-component.googleapis.com --project=project_name
gcloud services enable cloudbilling.googleapis.com --project=project_name
```

Comment: where did you find that information?